# iphone In App purchase question

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Assuming this scenario-
A user downloads a zip file A after in app purchase A. Then he updates the application to new version.

**Now, does he have to download the zip file A again or is it still there in the device?**

One more question : How do I verify that the zip file A has been downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is still on the device:

When upgrading, only the binary of the app is replaced (`.app`).
The *Documents* directory and *User defaults* remain untouched between two versions.

Comment: So how do I check for updates on my in app purchase downloads? Any clue on how should I manage the versions of my in app purchase downloads.

Comment: You want to provide a new version of a file *bought* with an in app purchase? What type of product is it (consumable or not)?

Comment: Apple does not provide such a update system for IAP. Though you can build your own: check (web service?) whether a new version is available and propose to re-download the file. As it's non consumable, the user could just go through the buying process again (he won't have to pay a second time).

Comment: That is what I am asking how to ensure that the user has latest version of in app purchase.

Comment: No choice but to have your own mechanism to track this (e.g. store the file version when it's downloaded and later check it against the latest file version on your server)

Comment: Well if suppose a user has downloaded in app purchase a.zip. Then technically can he download updated version of a.zip from the server?

Comment: Sure. That's definitely possible. Just replace the old file with the new downloaded one.